# JS regex for matching different #tags in URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I am in need of two regular expressions.
First of all I want to check if my URL contains the hashtag #videos. Then if it does, I want to get the value of the second #tag. That value could contain all kinds of characters;

http://local/default.php#videos#12345
http://local/default.php#videos#g5458f
http://local/default.php#videos#0-e4a5d

This is what I've got so far:

```
if (window.location.hash = 'videos') {
      var url = window.location.hash,
          id = url.match(regex-goes-here);  // output e.g string '12345'
}
```

(Not sure if my extremely simple check (window.location.hash = 'videos') will work on two hashtags..? There is probably a better way of checking the URL, if so, please do tell :-)

Comment: Okay obviously window.location.hash won't work if you have multiple hastags...

Comment: the second `#` is simply part of the hash, it's valid, eg. in case of 'http://local/default.php#videos#12345', `window.location.hash` will be `#videos#12345`

Comment: Ahh! That's why window.location.hash === '#videos' returned false. Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an array of tags like this:

```
var tags = window.location.hash.replace(/^#/, '').split('#');
```

In case of `http://local/default.php#videos#12345`, `tags[0]` will be **videos** and `tags[1]` will be **12345**. You can use `tags.length` to determine how many tags there are.

Comment: Neat and simple - love it! Thanks!